# Driver not found connecting to oracle DB with jaydebeapi

Tags: java, python, oracle, oracle11g, jaydebeapi

Trying to connect to a db but getting error:

```
conn = jaydebeapi.connect('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',                                     
                         jdbc:oracle:thin:@mydomain.com:1234:GP1', [ 'user', 'pass'],      
                         'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\ojdb6.jar')
```

Gives the error

```
File "C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\jpype\_jclass.py", line 55, in JClass
raise _RUNTIMEEXCEPTION.PYEXC("Class %s not found" % name)

java.lang.RuntimeExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class     
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver not found
```

My JAVA_HOME variable is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121`, and in that directory I have the ojdb6.jar file,  but I think that I am not correctly managing to set the CLASSPATH correctly. How do I do this?, and to what should I set it?

Have tried the instructions here but think I am not doing correctly.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html
e.g.

`set CLASSPATH C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121`
However when I commandline `echo %CLASSPATH%` it just comes back with `%CLASSPATH%` suggesting I have not done it right?
Or is there something else the problem?

Comment: You have to add the Oracle Driver jar to your classpath. It is not part of the jdk

Comment: Such error can mean only that OracleDriver is not in classpath. Add it to classpath

Comment: Thank you - but how do I do that? I do not know what my classpath is...

Comment: @JaySmith      _______

Comment: Do you use ide? If not then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath

Answer (score 0):

On Windows backslashes in path's have to be escaped or you can use raw strings:

```
conn = jaydebeapi.connect('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',                                     
                         jdbc:oracle:thin:@mydomain.com:1234:GP1', [ 'user', 'pass'],      
                         r'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\ojdb6.jar')
```

Alternatively you can set the environment variable `CLASSPATH` as described [in the JDK docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).